# Running commands on several files

Tags: bash

My script  (bash shell) extracts some numbers from file *026.s01

```
input=${input_dir}/*026.s01
seq=` cat $input |awk 'NR>3{print substr($2,5,7)}' | sort -n | head -1`
first_sht=` cat $input | awk 'NR>3{print int($3)}' | head -1`
last_sht=` cat $input | awk 'NR>3{print int($3)}' | tail -1`
echo " $seq $first_sht last_sht" |   awk '{printf("%6s%10s%9s\n",$1,$2,$3)}' >> dir_file_SEQ-$seq.txt.
```

How can I do this on multiple files `${input_dir}/*.s01`?

I tried to use :

```
for file in ${input_dir}/*.s01
do
done
echo " $seq $sail_line $src_dir" |   awk '{printf("%6s%10s%9s\n",$1,$2,$3)}' >> dir_file_SEQ-$seq.txt
```

But instead of getting several dir_file_SEQ-???.txt file I only have 1 file only called dir_file_SEQ-.txt with this content:

```
  Date       229         
  Date       409         
  Date       589         
  Date       769         
  Date       949         
  Date      1129
```

I assume "Date" comes from the error and it is nothing I asked to have, the second column has one of the values I asked but I still miss others.

Comment: Please format the code. Then, please mention the shell that you are using (bash?).

Answer (score 0):

A bash for loop should do it for you in no time:

`SRC_DIR=/root
for FILE in ${SRC_DIR}/*.mp4
do
    YOUR COMMANDS
done`

Comment: It doesn't work. May be because each single file has to be not just selected but even going trough commands like seq=` cat $input |awk 'NR>3{print substr($2,5,7)}' | sort -n | head -1`

Answer (score 0):

It works in this way

```
for file 
in /dir./*.s01

do
   input=$file
```